# linux, basic test to detect mechanical disks

Tags: linux-kernel, block-device

For example :

> ls /sys/block/
>
> loop0  loop2  loop4  loop6  ram0  ram10  ram12  ram14  ram2  ram4  ram6  ram8  sda  sdc loop1  loop3  loop5  loop7  ram1  ram11  ram13  ram15  ram3  ram5  ram7  ram9  sdb  sr0

try to detect if it is a mechanical hard-disk

> cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational
>
> 1

ok.

> cat /sys/block/ram1/queue/rotational
>
> 1

weird ...

( failing on kernel 3.0.0-12-server )

Is there another simple and most reliable test ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using **smartctl** (found in package **smartmontools**):

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda
```

Its output will include a line "Rotation Rate" which tells either the rotation rate of the device or if it is a Solid State Device.